# Find files which do not have read permissions for other

Tags: linux, bash, shell, unix, find

I want to get all files which do not have read permissions for others.
I've tried `find . -type f  -perm -o-r` and `find . -type f  -perm -o`
But they return all files. Seems I'm doing something wrong.

Thanks.

Comment: I've found some dummy workaround 
find . -type f -printf "%m:%p\n" | grep -E "740|640"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just search for anything that doesn't have the read permission for others:

```
find -not -perm -o=r
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
find . -type f ! -perm -o+r
```